# how to not count less as operator javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

My problem is that my AngularJS application has to get a record from a JSON file, but the record is named like this:
`something-XD`.
Clearly the application counts the - as an operator and I need to prevent this.
Is there someway to do that?

Example:

```
array.push({activities:somethingAllReadyGet.something-XD})
```

The `something-XD` is the record that I have to get from the data that I have already got, if I write something like that:

```
array.push({activities:somethingAllReadyGet.json['something-XD']})
```

it doesn't work, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `json["something-XD"]` instead `json.something-XD`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bracket notation for accessing properties with names that are not valid identifiers:

```
array.push({activities:somethingAllReadyGet['something-XD']})
```